# Ancient browser media photo

Tags: operating-system, architecture, netscape

Perhaps 15 years ago, I saw a photo which looked professional showing multiple media types all with labels for either Netscape v4 or the integrated Mozilla suite (which became SeaMonkey). At the very least this included 3.5, 5 and 8" floppies, but I suspect there were other types as well.

Does this ring a bell with anybody, is the photo still available, and can anybody comment on the story (e.g. was it taken to mark the retirement of certain target architectures)?

I was reminded of that by https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61178/why-does-the-eu-uk-trade-deal-have-the-7-bit-ascii-table-as-an-appendix which highlights that Netscape 4 is apparently mentioned in the "Brexit" withdrawal documents.

Comment: This sounds like the sort of prank that [foone](https://twitter.com/Foone) would attempt. Netscape 1.0 came on a single 3½" floppy, but 5¼" and especially 8" floppies were essentially dead media at the time.

Comment: I think it was genuine. I saw it in about 2007, and none of the media was particularly outlandish for the era.

Comment: 8" floppies were not in common use 2007. They were not even in common use 1997.

Comment: @UncleBod Indeed. Which was the point of both my question and, I suspect, the photo. As I've said, I can't remember all the medium types but I suspect there was at least one (QIC?) tape cartridge, and all were properly embellished with colour labels... and this was before colour printers were anything like as common as they are today.

Comment: I don't think any of these are what I was thinking of, but look at http://toastytech.com/good/fffloppies.html for example... that's FF 2.0 (i.e. circa 2006) on 8" floppy for a SunOS system.

Comment: 5¼" floppies went out of use roughly in 2000, and 8" floppies roughly in 1985.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd — Someone was having fun with the disks in those pictures. Sun workstations hardly ever came with floppy disk drives, and when they did, they were 3.5"

Comment: @Janka — I'd say 5.25" floppies went out of mainstream use way earlier. The last machines to use them (in any quantity) were probably Commodore's 8-bit machines, which died out in the early-to-mid 90s.

Comment: It depends on where in the world, but I agree with Michael, 5.25” was well in the minority by the mid-90s (which still could mean significant absolute numbers...). Many PCs were still sold with them by default alongside 3.5” drives in 91-92, for backwards compatibility, but not much after that. Books with disks also switched around then, as did pirate courier groups. However I worked with a newspaper in Cairo in 92 that still used Wang and Linotype systems with 8” drives...

Comment: Put another way, which machines that Netscape shipped for _ever_ used 8" floppies? Other than on the technicality that the Shugart bus technically allows you to connect one. The original PC shipped with 5.25" drives, and everything else Netscape supported was younger than that.

Comment: @Tommy (et al.) I didn't say that I believed that the media was current. I still don't think I've seen the photo I was thinking of and I think it had at least one tape cartridge in it... and I'd certainly seen that sort of media being used for software distribution into the 90s (some form of VAX in the particular case I'm thinking of). Apropos 8" discs, I certainly remember new variants being introduced in the mid-80s (supposedly with 5Mb capacity but only working reliably for 3), and it's not improbable that Navigator should be shipped on media to suit a server rather than a desktop system.

Comment: For deployment of large amounts of software to Workstation / Server class machines in the late 80s/early 90s, I've seen tape drives (QIC and DAT/DDS), and Syquest-style removable hard disks, until CD-ROMs became ubiquitous. I've not seen 8" floppies (or 5.25" floppies, for that matter; and very rarely 3.5" floppies.)